# Setting a value to a bean variable in Struts 1.2

Tags: java, struts-1

I am using Struts 1.2 for my application. I have declared a variable using the Struts taglib  like this:

```
<bean:define id="stringVar" type="java.lang.String" value="someValue" />
```

Now I want to assign some other value to this variable "stringVar" based on some conditions. I am not sure how to assign a value to this variable.

Any help on this please?

Regards,

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and learn the JSTL. Then use the `<c:set>` tag. Then do yourself another favor, and use something other than Struts, which is dead and obsolete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your advice....Clients won't obsolete their web applications looking at the technology the web developers are using :) I was aware of <c:set> but thought there might be some struts tag to do it hence posted this question. But anyways if there is not, then need to import the JSTL.jar and standard.jar :) Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Comment: bean:define is supposed to also replace a value by another, but they made the silly design choice of using `id` as an attribute, making it impossible to use bean:define twice with the same id in the same JSP.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. Post your comment as answer so that I can close this thread.

Comment: I don't consider that as an answer, so I won't. You can try using the JSTL, see if it fits your needs, and post your own answer if you want.

Comment: Note that Struts 1 is a very different animal than Struts 2. Saying things like "Struts is dead and obsolete" is misleading. Struts 1 is now beginning its official EOL process; Struts 2 is under active development.